# curl's behaviors different between running stand alone and in a bash for loop

Tags: bash, ssl, curl, certificate

The following code runs into error:

```
for i in {190..208}; do curl -k -F 'act=upload' -F 'apk=@apks/apk_${i}.apk' -F 'comment=md5: `md5 apks/apk_$i.apk`' https://username:password@myhost.com/; done
```

The server has an self-signed cert, so, I tried to turn off the ssl with -k. 
reponse:

```
curl: (26) SSL: unable to obtain common name from peer certificate
curl: (26) SSL: unable to obtain common name from peer certificate
curl: (26) SSL: unable to obtain common name from peer certificate
......
curl: (26) SSL: unable to obtain common name from peer certificate
```

But, if I change my command to:

```
for i in {190..208}; do echo "curl -k -F 'act=upload' -F 'apk=@apks/apk_${i}.apk' -F 'comment=md5: `md5 apks/apk_$i.apk`' https://username:password@myhost.com/" >> tmp.sh; done

bash tmp.sh
```

It works without any warning.

I have no idea why.

Thank you.

P.S.
Some info.

```
logan $ uname -a
Darwin Logans-MacBook.local 10.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.0: Sat Jan 29 15:17:16 PST 2011; root:xnu-1504.9.37~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
logan $ /usr/bin/curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8l zlib/1.2.3
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap http file https ftps 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Comment: Quoting issue? run it by placing an "-x" after the bash-shebang and compare the output to verify that everything is expanded as expected. Try changing ' into "

Comment: Thank you @Fredrik, why do you answer me by commenting instead of create an Answer? I don't even have a chance to vote your answer up.

Comment: The question is answered perfectly. It is about Quoting issue. Do I need to close it or do sth else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have mentioned using "" instead of '' to correctly expand the ${i} variable.

However, this shouldn't have an effect on curl's SSL checking. To answer your general question about "why does bash behave differently with A and B", try comparing the output seen with `set -x`. This shows exactly what is being executed by the shell, after variable substitution and quote processing. A short example:

```
$ set -x
$ echo -k "My shell is ${SHELL}" 'and my homedir is ${HOME}'
+ echo -k 'My shell is /bin/bash' 'and my homedir is ${HOME}'
-k My shell is /bin/bash and my homedir is ${HOME}
```

If you compare bash's output with the "+"-prefixed lines, you should spot how the shell is interpreting the line in both command-line and tmp.sh.

Comment: Thanks, the `set -x` helps a lot. And I fixed it after change the quotes. How could I reverse the `set -x`?

Comment: @Logan, `set +x` is the opposite of `set -x`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes in your command. If you use `'` the variable `$i` is not expanded as well as the command substitution (`md5 apks/apk_$i.apk`) is not executed.

Comment: Thank you. Just like what you said.